# Slide window open animation not working properly [Titanium]

Tags: ios, animation, window, titanium, slidetoggle

Creating an iOS app in which press a button open a window by sliding it to the right. However, if I go from portrait mode to landscape or vice-versa; and then I if I press the button, the window slides in from top left for the first time instead of sliding form the left.

How can I fix this ?

Code :

```
 var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({left:0});

 var slideLeft = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
   slideLeft.left = 0; 
   slideLeft.duration = 200;

  var slide_it_right = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    slide_it_right.left = -320; 
    slide_it_right.duration = 300;

  button.addEventListener('click',function(){
              win.open(slideLeft);
  });
  win.addEventListener('swipe',function(){
          win.close(slideRight);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer following links

1. [Titanium: how to transition Slide left/right or up/down between 2 windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135606/titanium-how-to-transition-slide-left-right-or-up-down-between-2-windows/11176505#11176505)
2. [Titanium: Slide window left/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665247/titanium-slide-window-left-right?rq=1).

I hope you'll get something valuable from here